# What are some disadvantages of having very shallow inheritance tree (in java)?

Tags: inheritance, computer-science

I am reading a question from my review and I am not sure what are some disadvantages of having very shallow inheritance tree. I know the disadvantages of having very deep inheritance tree (because of confusion). But I am not sure the other part.

Help will be appreciated

thanks